# how to send an SMS without users interaction in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am actually trying to send SMS from my flutter app without user's interaction.
I know I can launch the SMS app using url_launcher but I actually want to send an SMS without user's interaction or launching SMS from my flutter app.

Please can someone tell me if this is possible.

Many Thanks,
Mahi

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually to send an SMS programatically, you'll need to implement a platform channel and use `SMSManager` to send SMS.

Example:

Android Part:

First add appropriate permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Then in your `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.yourcompany.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "sendSms";

  private MethodChannel.Result callResult;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if(call.method.equals("send")){
                   String num = call.argument("phone");
                   String msg = call.argument("msg");
                   sendSMS(num,msg,result);
                }else{
                  result.notImplemented();
                }
              }
            });
  }

  private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg,MethodChannel.Result result) {
      try {
          SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
          smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
          result.success("SMS Sent");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          result.error("Err","Sms Not Sent","");
      }
  }

}
```

Dart Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Rotation Demo",
    home: new SendSms(),
  ));
}


class SendSms extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SendSmsState createState() => new _SendSmsState();
}

class _SendSmsState extends State<SendSms> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('sendSms');

  Future<Null> sendSms()async {
    print("SendSMS");
    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('send',<String,dynamic>{"phone":"+91XXXXXXXXXX","msg":"Hello! I'm sent programatically."}); //Replace a 'X' with 10 digit phone number
      print(result);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new FlatButton(onPressed: () => sendSms(), child: const Text("Send SMS")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helped!

** Note:

1.The example code dosen't show how to handle permission on android devices with version `6.0` and above. If using with `6.0` implement the right permission invoking code.

2.The example also dosen't implement choosing sim incase of dual sim handsets. If no default sim is set for sms on dual sim handsets, sms might not be sent.

Comment: Thanks @Hemanth Raj you're really helpful and I will implement a platform channel for this. I am hoping that I will not be stuck trying to figure out which  SIM card to use to send SMS. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi @Hemanth Raj I used this code but got this error MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send  please help me if i doing anything wrong thank you.

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and then run.

Comment: @HemanthRaj sir. any way to read sms for otp  in flutter. I tried to modify your code to receive sms but not successful.

Comment: Hi @BilalŞimşek, some code would be helpful. Probably you should be able to achieve it modifying above code.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @Vaibhav Bhavsar. I have tried `flutter clean`, `flutter run`, and creating a new project. I am able to get it to request video and audio, but not sms. I wonder if this `MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel sendSms))` will stop occurring once I can figure out how to access the permission? I'm using `permission_handler`. When I created a new project, the `permission_handler` usage changed from `PermissionHandler` to `Permission`, but it still did not request sms permission. Any ideas?

Comment: Same MissingPluginExceptin when trying to use this, unfortunately.

Comment: @sigma1510 You need to restart the app, hot restart might give such errors when plugin code is not available.

Comment: @HemanthRaj I tried restarting the app, flutter clean, cleared the intellij caches, restarted intellij, uninstalled and reinstalled the entire app, and created a new emulator to run the app on. The error persisted and I ended up kicking out telephony and switching to the sms_maintained plugin, which works. Hopefully the issue in telephony can be resolved, but it does not seem to be a "turn it off and on again" issue.

Answer (score 9):

This is the old lib that I've used before,

Link: [sms_maintained](https://github.com/geordyvcErasmus/flutter_sms)

note: this is a fork of a previous flutter sms library which was not maintained any more and hence the name. this one is currently active and working.

But as of 2021, I've switched to [telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony) and quite happy with it.

Comment: Excellent Work,the original plugin isn't wokring and ur's done the job.

Comment: Brother, the plugin is great. Thank you. But there is a problem when sending sms with letter " ň " in the sms. Why is it so? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Ok... brother, I think I found the exact problem, its not the letter itself... the maximum length of normal text sms is 170 for letters like [a,b...z] because in this case 1 letter = 1 byte.... but for letters like ň , 1 letter = 2 byte... so the limit is 140. That means the maximum length of sms will be 70 [70 x ň = 140 bytes]. But this is not a problem with default android sms because it is using some kind of headers to split the long message and concatenate on the receiver's end. I don't have much knowledge on this. If you can find a solution, please do share. Thank you.

Comment: @Ali80, how did you send SMS to multiple contacts at the same time using telephony package?