# Flutter send sms with device automatically

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter

I found this code [how to send an SMS without users interaction in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287206/how-to-send-an-sms-without-users-interaction-in-flutter) in another stackoverflow thread.
But it doesn't seem to work anymore. When I start flutter the app is assembling and starting but then it crashes automatically.

I think the problem lies in the Android-Code. Unfortunately IntelliJ doesn't show any errors.

```
package com.yourcompany.example;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "sendSms";

  private MethodChannel.Result callResult;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if(call.method.equals("send")){
                   String num = call.argument("phone");
                   String msg = call.argument("msg");
                   sendSMS(num,msg,result);
                }else{
                  result.notImplemented();
                }
              }
            });
  }

  private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg,MethodChannel.Result result) {
      try {
          SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
          smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
          result.success("SMS Sent");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          result.error("Err","Sms Not Sent","");
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify the android code as follows and this should work.

Android-Code:

```
package com.yourcompany.smsdemo;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "sendSms";

  // private MethodChannel.Result callResult;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      if (checkSelfPermission(
              Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
              != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

          // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
          // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
          // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

          // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

          requestPermissions(
                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                  0);

          // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS is an
          // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
          // result of the request.
        }
      }
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (call.method.equals("send")) {
                  String num = call.argument("phone");
                  String msg = call.argument("msg");
                  sendSMS(num, msg, result);
                } else {
                  result.notImplemented();
                }
              }
            });
  }

  private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    try {
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
      result.success("SMS Sent");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      result.error("Err", "Sms Not Sent", "");
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case 0: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

          // permission was granted, yay! Do the
          // contacts-related task you need to do.

        } else {

          // permission denied, boo! Disable the
          // functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
        return;
      }

      // other 'case' lines to check for other
      // permissions this app might request.
    }
  }
}
```

and also include the below line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

I've actually modified @HemanthRaj's code and added runtime permissions from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java).
Please let me know if this worked. Many Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped I think the problem was that permissions weren't granted. Now it works

Comment: hi Johannes, Thank you for your reply. Glad, it worked. happy coding and just accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `Kotlin` code of [@Mahi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315119/1766014)'s solution:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    // private MethodChannel.Result callResult;

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(
                            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                            0)

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }
            }
        }
        MethodChannel(getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "send") {
                val num = call.argument<String>("phone")
                val msg = call.argument<String>("msg")
                sendSMS(num, msg, result)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getBinaryMessenger(): BinaryMessenger? {
        return flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger
    }

    private fun sendSMS(phoneNo: String?, msg: String?, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        try {
            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null)
            result.success("SMS Sent")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            result.error("Err", "Sms Not Sent", "")
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            0 -> {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL = "sendSms"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One import statement is missing, also edited the previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287206/how-to-send-an-sms-without-users-interaction-in-flutter/48295328#48295328) to add the import statement.

Just add this import statement:

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
```

Hope it helped!