# Flutter : How we can use inbuilt message app for send message using package?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to send a message from my inbuilt default message application, But I don't know how I can send a message using **dart code [*flutter*]**

Answer (score 1):

Actually to send an SMS programatically, you'll need to implement a platform channel and use SMSManager to send SMS.

Example:

Android Part:

First add appropriate permissions to AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Then in your `MainActivity.java`:

```
  public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "sendSms";

  private MethodChannel.Result callResult;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if(call.method.equals("send")){
                   String num = call.argument("phone");
                   String msg = call.argument("msg");
                   sendSMS(num,msg,result);
                }else{
                  result.notImplemented();
                }
              }
            });
  }

  private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg,MethodChannel.Result result) {
      try {
          SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
          smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
          result.success("SMS Sent");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          result.error("Err","Sms Not Sent","");
      }
  }

}
```

Dart Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Rotation Demo",
    home: new SendSms(),
  ));
}


class SendSms extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SendSmsState createState() => new _SendSmsState();
}

class _SendSmsState extends State<SendSms> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('sendSms');

  Future<Null> sendSms()async {
    print("SendSMS");
    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('send',<String,dynamic>{"phone":"+91XXXXXXXXXX","msg":"Hello! I'm sent programatically."}); //Replace a 'X' with 10 digit phone number
      print(result);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new FlatButton(onPressed: () => sendSms(), child: const Text("Send SMS")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[refrence link for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287206/how-to-send-an-sms-without-users-interaction-in-flutter)

Comment: Hi @Prashant Jajal this is not work for me got this error "MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel sendSms)" plz help me Thank you.